# JS timer displays NaN in IE8

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer-8

I have built a countdown timer using pure JS and it all seems to work fine until I get to IE8. Using IE8 returns NaN in the timer fields.

I realise that moment is a good library for working with date/time fields but I wanted to try and get it working with good old JS (no libraries). This is why I convert the dates to UNIX in order to do some simple maths.

Here's the JS I've used:

```
(function(){
  // Setup all the variables needed
  var week = document.getElementById('timer-weeks');
  var day = document.getElementById('timer-days');
  var hour = document.getElementById('timer-hours');
  var min = document.getElementById('timer-minutes');
  var sec = document.getElementById('timer-seconds');
  var target = new Date('2017-01-17T08:00:00Z').getTime();
  setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var d = target - now;

    // Get number of weeks until event
    var weeks = Math.floor(d/604800000);
    week.innerHTML = weeks;

    // Remove weeks from d variable and work out days
    d = d - (weeks * 604800000);
    var days = Math.floor(d/86400000);
    day.innerHTML = days;

    // Remove days from d variable and work out hours
    d = d - (days * 86400000);
    var hours = Math.floor(d/3600000);
    hour.innerHTML = hours;

    // Remove hours from d variable and work out minutes
    d = d - (hours * 3600000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(d/60000);
    min.innerHTML = minutes;

    // Remove minutes from d variable and work out seconds
    d = d - (minutes * 60000);
    var seconds = Math.floor(d/1000);
    sec.innerHTML = seconds;

  }, 1000);

}());
```

Here's the link to the Codepen: http://codepen.io/MattJLeach/pen/JEdXoZ

Thank you for any help you can give

Comment: Well you need to debug (or with IE8 insert alerts() at various points) to see whats not a number when one is expected... Start by ensuring the string format passed to the Date() ctor is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE 8, but from memory it does not parse ISO 8601 date strings. You should not be doing that anyway, since parsing with the Date constructor (or Date.parse) is not a good idea.

The pre–ES5 equivalent of:

```
new Date('2017-01-17T08:00:00Z').getTime();
```

is

```
Date.UTC(2017,0,17,8,0,0);
```

which is compatible everywhere and also less to type. ;-)

```js
// Should fail in IE 8 and other pre ES5 implementaitons
console.log(new Date('2017-01-17T08:00:00Z').getTime());

// Compatible everywhere
console.log(Date.UTC(2017,0,17,8,0,0));
```

BTW, your code can be a little more concise:

```js
(function(){
  // Setup all the variables needed
  var tgtDate = document.getElementById('timer-date'); 
  var week = document.getElementById('timer-weeks');
  var day = document.getElementById('timer-days');
  var hour = document.getElementById('timer-hours');
  var min = document.getElementById('timer-minutes');
  var sec = document.getElementById('timer-seconds');
  var target = Date.UTC(2017,1,17,8);
  tgtDate.innerHTML = new Date(target).toString();
  setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var d = target - now;

    // Get number of weeks until event
    week.innerHTML =  d/6.048e8 | 0;
    day.innerHTML  = (d % 6.048e8)/8.64e7 | 0;
    hour.innerHTML = (d % 8.64e7 )/3.6e6  | 0;
    min.innerHTML  = (d % 3.6e6  )/6e4    | 0;
    sec.innerHTML  = (d % 6e4    )/1e3    | 0;

  }, 1000);
 }());
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-top: 1px solid #999999;
  border-left: 1px solid #999999;
}
th, td {
  border-right: 1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
#timer-date {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th colspan="5">Time left to <span id="timer-date"></span>
  <tr><th>Weeks
      <th>Days
      <th>Hours
      <th>Minutes
      <th>Seconds
  <tr><td id="timer-weeks">&nbsp;
      <td id="timer-days">&nbsp;
      <td id="timer-hours">&nbsp;
      <td id="timer-minutes">&nbsp;
      <td id="timer-seconds">&nbsp;
</table>
```

Using *setInterval* for a clock that ticks every second isn't recommended as it does not run at exactly 1 second intervals, it will slowly drift so appear to skip a second every now and then. Consider using *setTimeout* and calling the function just after the next full second.